# Multiple mappers for small file

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, teradata, sqoop

I'm working on an ETL application based on Hive. One functional requirement is that we export some of the data in Hive to Teradata (which is the existing solution being used) and vice versa. My issue is related to the export.

I'm using sqoop with Teradata connector to export the HDFS files. Some of the files, although they have a hundred K records, are quite small ~ 7MB. So sqoop uses only a single mapper while doing the export (I specified -m option but it did not work). This becomes quite a slow process.

Is there any way to divide the data in a single file (smaller than HDFS block size) among multiple mappers in the cluster?

(Since imports are fast because of sqoop dividing the rows among mappers, this has become a point of comparison and I have to make the export work faster)

Edit:- Software versions:
Hadoop: MapR M3 - hadoop 0.20
Sqoop: 1.4.2
Teradata Connector for Sqoop: 1.0.5

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with precise versions of Hadoop, Sqoop and Teradata connector that you're running? Also would you mind sharing precise Sqoop commands that you're using with short description of what is the outcome? The -m parameter should work (even for files smaller than one hdfs block).

Comment: Here is the exact sqoop command generated by my program:
sqoop export --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver --connect jdbc:teradata://<hostname>/<dbname> -m 4 --username testusr --password testusr --table <teradatadb>.<teradatatbl> --export-dir /path/to/hdfs/dump/created/from/hive --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --batch


I have also tries replacing '-m 4' with '--num-mappers 4'